# Is it easy for a PHP Developer to create own framework?

Tags: frameworks, imdb

I would like to create a website similar like imdb.com. Whether imdb.com uses any framework? if so which framework it uses? Otherwise are they developing on their own? Is it easy for a normal PHP developer to create my own php framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a PHP developer:

- I have my own php framework, So you can say it's not so hard; But you must first learn how other frameworks work... And decide what your framework need to do... Which design patters you agree with...
- Most of big websites didn't use famous frameworks, Or even their own frameworks... Mostly using a plenty of libraries... Because when you use a framework you code faster but you waste resources as RAM, CPU IO/Disk...

A well programmed application is this one that use 100% of its code source, It's good to go OOP, MVC... But not in the way most of frameworks works... This what is life less working time cause a less quality project.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons why you would want to create your own framework:

1. Learning purposes, it's a great learning opportunity because you
   will learn a lot.
2. This one I highly doubt is a issue for you, but
   If you believe your framework can be different and better in some
   way than those already existing, go for it.

A framework isn't the application, a framework is a tool set that lets you get straight on the application itself, instead of writing a database abstraction layer you learn how built-in in works and writes the busniess logic your application needs.

Answer (score 0):

Developing a new framework is not a trivial or easy work at all. Even for a team is difficult to handle, so be extremely sure you need to create yet another one before starting.

Instead, use open source, well known solutions, so that bugs are likely to be triaged and fixed. There are many which are available even for commercial use. Just choose your favourite one: [Symfony](http://symfony.com/), [Code Igniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/) or [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/) or whatever and start building your application on top.

As of IMDB, probably they are using a framework, but there is no way to tell what if any.